# Sharing screens/monitor between Asus Laptop and iMac

Tags: imac, windows, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I have the following equipment:

- An iMac 27" (mid-2011 windows 8 BOOTCAMP with 2 thunderbolt port and 1 miniDisplayPort)
- An ASUS ROG laptop (with 1x VGA port/Mini D-sub 15-pin for external monitor / Mini display-port / 1 x HDMI)
- An External monitor with HDMI, VGA and DVI input.

I want to use the display on my iMac as a 2nd screen from my asus laptop, leaving the iMac to use the external Monitor instead of it's own screen.  Essentially, I would like to use the iMac screen as an external monitor *while still having the iMac running a full OS, not just being used an a monitor*.  Is it possible for this iMac to either a) receive input to be used as an external monitor, and b) if so, can it still be used as a computer at this point?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible...

The closest you can get to that is by using [Target Display Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924) as described [here](http://science.opposingviews.com/use-imac-pc-monitor-9320.html). The problem, though, is that [TDM is only available when running OS X on the iMac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924#8). Furthermore, you won't be able to use the iMac even though it's *technically* running.

Judging from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114259/strange-behaviour-of-target-display-mode-with-imac-mac-mini-and-thunderbolt-dis/) here at Ask Different, TDM doesn't seem to support multiple displays while running anyway.

I've looked at this before and did some research for this question, and I was unable to find anything beyond streaming the contents in an AirPlay-like fashion, which I doubt is usable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try network based solutions like ScreenRecycler, Spacedesk or MaxiVista.

Try this link: http://alternativeto.net/software/maxivista/

Comment: You may want to include references to all applications and link directly to the vendor's web site to avoid having this look like spam.